# Call minified browser javascript in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an enormous minified javascript file (with no browser specific calls) but several functions that I need to use.  Is there a systematic way to convert such a file so that it is callable in node?  The js is wrapped in a self executing anonymous function.  The function ends with .call(this)

Answer (score 2):

The very least you would need to do is export something from that file, so you could load it as a module and consume it from your other Node code.

```
 exports.myThing = somethingFromMyFile;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your description, I am assuming that the file is of the format

```
(function () {

  // file contents

  this.someFunction = function() {
     // function contents
  }

}).call(this);
```

When executed in the browser `window` object gets passed as `this` and all the properties like `someFunction` are attached to window.

To use it as a module in node, you could bind the function to an empty object and export that object. For example,

```
var obj = {};

(function () {

  // file contents

  this.someFunction = function() {
     // function contents
  }

}).call(obj);

module.exports = obj;
```

Then use it like

```
var mymodule= require('./mymodule');

mymodule.someFunction();
```